# How to filter JSON String array based on attributes?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON-String array, where its entry has the following properties, *firstName*, *lastName*, *loginName*, *Country*, *phoneNumber*, and *status*. Here's an example

```
[  
    {  
        "firstName": "Patrick",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "loginName":"test0003@test.com",
        "Country":"US",
        "phoneNumber": "287 125-1434",
        "status": "340"
    },
    {  
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "lastName": "Williams",
        "loginName":"test0002@test.com",
        "Country":"US",
        "phoneNumber": "213 111-9943",
        "status": "215"
    },
    {  
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Johnson",
        "loginName":"test0001@test.com",
        "Country":"DE",
        "phoneNumber": "212 555-1234",
        "status": "167"
    },
    {  
        "firstName": "George",
        "lastName": "Jones",
        "loginName":"test0004@test.com",
        "Country":"FR",
        "phoneNumber": "217 987-2634",
        "status": "340"
    }
]
```

Now, I want to search for a specific entry based on the properties *loginName* and *status*

For example

- **loginName:** test0001@test.com
- **status:** 167

  ```
  {  
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Johnson",
      "loginName":"test0001@test.com",
      "Country":"DE",
      "phoneNumber": "212 555-1234",
      "status": "167"
  }
  ```

What would be the most optimized solution?

Comment: Google "java json" and select a library. Once you've tried using it and gotten stuck, ask again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Jackson, this is the crudest snippet I can think of:

```
private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(filterJsonArray(JSON, "loginName", "test0001@test.com", "status", "167"));
}

public static String filterJsonArray(String array, String keyOne, Object valueOne, String keyTwo, Object valueTwo) throws IOException {
    Map[] nodes = mapper.readValue(array, HashMap[].class);

    for (Map node : nodes) {
        if (node.containsKey(keyOne) && node.containsKey(keyTwo)) {
            if (node.get(keyOne).equals(valueOne) && node.get(keyTwo).equals(valueTwo)) {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Of course it will only returns the first match to the given pairs. If you need all the values, make it return a list instead and populate it inside the loop.

Comment: Writing that sentence here is like saying "I want a salad" at MCDonalds... what I mean is it is not the place for that.

Comment: @efthialex I may sound like a douche, but there isn't much to explain. Your json array is simply a collection of json objects, which I used Jackson to parse and represent as Objects (collection of Maps). Having the objects at hand we can just use the default Map api to search for the entries we want. The given snippet may look generic enough to be used with other jsons, but it is not the case as it requires you to always search for 2 values. This is the reason I said it is crude and there is a lot of room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I use JSONObject and here is another way to parse. 
1. Parse using `JSONArray`
2. Loop the array and read into UserProfile objects
3. Store it in HashMap to get using key

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.*;

class UserProfile{
  String loginName;
  int status;
  String firstName;
  String key;

  UserProfile(){

  }

  String getLoginName(){
    return loginName;
  }

  String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
  }

  void setKey(String key){
    this.key = key;
  }

  void setLoginName(String loginName){
    this.loginName = loginName;
  }

  void setStatus(int status){
    this.status = status;
  }

  void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
}

public class JSONObjParser {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<String, UserProfile> map = new HashMap<String, UserProfile>();

    String msg ="[{ firstName: Patrick, lastName: Smith, loginName:test0003@test.com, Country:US, phoneNumber: 287 125-1434, status: 340 }, {  firstName: Bob, lastName: Williams, loginName:test0002@test.com, Country:US, phoneNumber: 213 111-9943, status: 215 }]";
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(msg);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        String loginName = jsonobject.getString("loginName");
        int status = jsonobject.getInt("status");
        String firstName = jsonobject.getString("firstName");

        UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();
        profile.setFirstName(firstName);
        profile.setLoginName(loginName);
        profile.setStatus(status);
        String key = loginName + Integer.toString(status);
        map.put(key, profile);
    }

    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        UserProfile profile = map.get(key);
        System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", FirstName = " + profile.getFirstName());
    }

  }
}
```