# How do I filter Json data using a attribute in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have JSON object that looks like

```
{
    "1F54716": [],
    "1258820b-guid": [
        {
            "value": "true",
            "property": "",
            "say": "Hello",

        },
        {
            "value": "false",
            "property": "",
            "say": "Hello",

        }
    ],

}
```

Is there a way I can filter this by "value": "true", so only have values , where value =true , and then I want a count of say ==Hello . Really appreciate your help , new to javascript world

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749119/how-to-filter-json-string-array-based-on-attributes see this

Comment: This is not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var theObject = {"1F54716": [], "1258820b-guid": [
    {"value": "true", "property": "", "say": "Hello"},
    {"value": "false", "property": "", "say": "Hello"},
    {"value": "true", "property": "", "say": "Bye"},
    {"value": "true", "property": "", "say": "Hello"}
]}; // Array has 3 value "true" objects and 2 of them count as say "Hello".

function extractArrayWithValueAndSay(obj) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj[k] && obj[k].length && "value" in obj[k][0] && "say" in obj[k][0]) {
            return obj[k];
        }
    }
    return [];
}

var sourceArray = extractArrayWithValueAndSay(theObject);

var filteredValueTrueArray = sourceArray.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj && obj.value == "true";
});

var filteredSayHelloCount = filteredValueTrueArray.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj && obj.say == "Hello";
}).length;
```

Comment: ["1258820b-guid"] is actually a guid and will change everytime for different things . How do I use a generic value here ?

Comment: Added a function to detect and extract the source array based on the existing properties 'value' and 'say'.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a check for the property.

```js
var data = { "1F54716": [], "1258820b-guid": [ { "value": "true", "property": "", "say": "Hello", }, { "value": "false", "property": "", "say": "Hello", } ], },
    count;

// filter all properties
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
    data[k] = data[k].filter(function (a) {
        return a.value === "true";
    });
});

// count
count = Object.keys(data).reduce(function (r, k) {
    return data[k].reduce(function (rr, a) {
        return rr + +(a.say === 'Hello');
    }, r);
}, 0);

console.log(data);
console.log(count);
```

Comment: ["1258820b-guid"] is actually a guid and will change everytime for different things . How do I use a generic value here ?

Comment: does it have a common pattern, or do you need all properties filtered?

Comment: I need to filter by all properties

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
function filterObj(obj) {
  let res = {};
  let res.count = 0;
  // iterate through all keys in the object
  Object.keys(obj).forEach( k => {  
    // if this sub-object has 
    res[k] = obj[k].filter(o => {
    // if say = hello increment our counter by 1. Otherwise it stays the same
    res.count += o.say === 'hello' ? 1 : 0;
    // if the  object has value === true, keep it in our final results
    return o.value === "true";
   });
  );
  // res.count is the number of say === 'hello'
  // and res contains only objects with value === 'true' 
  return res;
}
```

Should work. Another solution would be to JSON parse the object and just use o.value as the test to keep it, depending on whether you plan to continue processing this object in JS or are serializing it next.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Underscore.js framework. It provides a variety of ways to search data into javascript array.

```
    var obj =  {
"1F54716": [],
"1258820b-guid": [
    {
        "value": "true",
        "property": "",
        "say": "Hello",

    },
    {
        "value": "false",
        "property": "",
        "say": "Hello",

    }
],
}
var result = _.where(obj["1258820b-guid"], { value : "true"});
```

Here's [Official website Underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) for furthur reading.